# Where should I look for consumers key and secret in order to register OAuth?

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to register OAuth from R in order to analyze tweets (using twitteR and ROAuth packages), but I don't know how to get consumers key and secret key. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The project [vignette for twitteR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/vignettes/twitteR.pdf) discusses this to some degree. It's in section 6 (page 7).

Syntax examples are even given:

```
> cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = YOURKEY, consumerSecret = YOURSECRET,
+ requestURL = requestURL, accessURL = accessURL, authURL = authURL)
> cred$handshake()
```

Comment: For some unknown reason this code works only if I replace all https with http. Anyway, it works. I guess.