# How can I get ALL (i.e., 1500+) the tweets w/a given hashtag over a given period?

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I am trying to get all the tweets that contain a hashtag (say #rstats) ocer the past two years (say Jan 11 to Dec 12). Using searchTwitter, however, only returns up to 1500. I think (based on some reading) that I have to login in order to be able to query more than 1500 tweets.
Now, I am on a Mac OS, using R (I am open to using Python, if a simple straightforward solution exists there) and can't log in; running this

```
requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = twt.name, consumerSecret = twt.pass, requestURL = requestURL, accessURL = accessURL, authURL = authURL)
twitCred$handshake()
```

returns:

```
Error in twitCred$handshake():
Invalid response from site, please check your consumerKey and consumerSecret and try again.
```

I appreciate that if someone helps me with getting this working.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to replace all https with http?

Have you seen this:

[Where should I look for consumers key and secret in order to register OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713244/where-should-i-look-for-consumers-key-and-secret-in-order-to-register-oauth)

Comment: I managed to make this work ... apparently, I should have setup a dev account, which I didn't.
Now, when I ask for 2000 tweets, it doesn't work; it returns Forbidden error. Do you know how that can happen?